# Installing shared library - questions and problems

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking

I'm having trouble "installing" a shared library I download online. The library name is run time access (http://www.runtimeaccess.com/). In the quick start guide, they explain how to use the library using -L when compiling to define the library location and exporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable after adding the path of the library dir.
First of all why do you need to define the lib location twice? using -L and LD_Library_PATH env variable?

Second part. I'm trying to avoid passing these arguments and also avoiding modification of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env, so all I have to do is compile like so:

```
$ gcc myapp.c -lrtadb
```

so I would like to include the lib as part of the system lib. So I copied the whole `rta-0.8.1` folder to `/usr/local/lib/rta-0.8.1` and then add a `/etc/ld.conf.d/rtadb.conf` file containing the path of the library directory `/usr/local/lib/rta-0.8.1/src` in there.

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/rtadb.conf 
#rta (run time access) lib
/usr/local/lib/rta-0.8.1/src
```

and then I ran `sudo ldconfig` to update the shared library list - but no luck. When I try to compile my code, the library is not found:

```
$gcc myappdb.c -lrtadb
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrtadb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong here?

here is the list of files in /usr/local/lib/rta-0.8.1/src

```
user@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/rta-0.8.1/src$ ls -l
total 724
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24994 2012-11-14 10:49 api.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26132 2012-11-14 11:07 api.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62634 2012-11-14 10:49 do_sql.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5419 2012-11-14 10:49 do_sql.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41184 2012-11-14 11:07 do_sql.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 149186 2012-11-14 11:07 librtadb.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 2012-11-14 11:07 librtadb.so -> librtadb.so.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 2012-11-14 11:07 librtadb.so.3 -> librtadb.so.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 117749 2012-11-14 11:07 librtadb.so.3.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2387 2012-11-14 10:49 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10962 2012-11-14 11:07 parse.output
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21929 2012-11-14 11:07 parse.tab.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    425 2012-11-14 11:07 parse.tab.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25064 2012-11-14 11:07 parse.tab.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6711 2012-11-14 10:49 parse.y
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  46636 2012-11-14 10:49 rta.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31551 2012-11-14 10:49 rtatables.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17028 2012-11-14 11:07 rtatables.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58843 2012-11-14 11:07 token.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6291 2012-11-14 10:49 token.l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  37996 2012-11-14 11:07 token.o
```

btw, I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

thank you.

edit: if your new to this info read link below:
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the `ld` where to look for the library, since it is not in one of the default directories. Since the linker is called by `gcc`, use the latter's `-L` option.

```
gcc -lrtadb -L/usr/local/lib/rta-0.8.1/src
```

should do it in your case.

Comment: But I placed the library path as part of the default lib directories in the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ files.

Comment: `/etc/ld.conf*` is information for the runtime linker `ldd`, that resolves what shared libraries to load in application address space. `ld` is a compile time linker - it actually embeds the references to the required symbols into the binary.

Comment: ok that explains it.Thx, But in any case, how can I avoid explicitly defining the library path. example if I use -sdl or -pthead I don't specify the location of the library.

Comment: because they live in "standard" directories (/lib*, /usr/lib*, and probably /usr/local/lib*). If you move your library there, it should start working without the `-L` option. But be careful about that, since it would likely pollute your system in a sense, that the files would not be owned by any packages (assuming you are using a distribution with a packaging system).